# ODE with tridiagonal anti-Hermitian matrix and initial condition in one entry

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems, matrix-exponential

I am given an [anti-Hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-Hermitian_matrix) and tridiagonal matrix $\bf M$ and I need to solve for a vector $\bf v$ such that

$$ \left[ \exp( t {\bf M} ) \, {\bf v} \right]_{1} = {\bf 0} $$

or at least $\approx {\bf 0}$. I am equally interested in the case where this holds $\forall t\ge0$ as well as after some finite $t_c$.

As of now, I do not have any clue how to schematically tackle this problem to get non-trivial solutions, especially for the second case.

Comment: Have you considered using the Jordan decomposition of $\bf M$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo could you expand a little on this? I understand how this can be used to solve the ODE for some initial condition but I don't see how the condition in question can be enforced for later $t$

Comment: Assume that $\bf M$ is diagonalisable.  Rephrasing, you want a linear combination of the entries of $\exp(t {\bf \Lambda})$ to be zero. Is this even possible? How will the exponentials cancel each other?